# Star of David Math Puzzle

Tags: arithmetic, puzzle

My son brought the following puzzle home from his 3rd grade math class.

[image]

Are there any strategies for solving it besides brute force?

Comment: Try a $6$ by $4$ matrix.

Comment: @Jossie Maybe you could expound a bit?

Comment: [
a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4;
b_1, b_2, b_3, b_4; 
a_1 + c_2 + b_2 + c_4; 
a_4 + d_2 + b_3 + c_4; 
b_1 + c_2 + a_2 + e_4; 
b_4 + d_2 + a_3 + e_4;
] set all of the rows equal to 26 and solve for the linear system.

Comment: @Jossie It would be interesting to see you solve it. How would you account for the fact that they must be distinct integers from 1 to 12? Also, there are 80 solutions (up to rotation/reflection). Can you explain why this is so?

Comment: To answer your second question, those solutions are just isomorphic graphs to the star of david. So it's really nothing significant.

Comment: To answer your first question, notice there are 6 numbers (vertices) with degree 4 and 2, respectively. this leads to 24 + 12 = 36, the total number of variables (without replacing c_1 with a_1 for example).

Comment: See please my answer to related question here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/499587/how-to-solve-this-system-of-linear-equations/499713#499713

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These kinds of problems are special because we're only looking for *one* solution, so that we can make educated guesses to stumble upon one.

In a magic square, 1 and the maximum number are usually paired. But in this puzzle, unlike a magic square, every number is included in exactly two sums. This gives us freedom we wouldn't normally have. We can pair 1 with 12 on the outside, but because of this freedom, we can put the next-most-extreme numbers together, to give us a place to start from:
$$\begin{array}{ccccccc}
 &  &  & 1\\
? &  & ? &  & 2 &  & ?\\
 & ? &  &  &  & 11\\
? &  & ? &  & ? &  & 12\\
 &  &  & ?
\end{array}$$

There is one undetermined number in a sum with 11 and a sum with 12. That can probably be made as small as possible: 3. (We could have done this symmetrically with 1 and 2 needing a big number, but probably not both at the same time.)

$$\begin{array}{ccccccc}
 &  &  & 1\\
? &  & ? &  & 2 &  & ?\\
 & ? &  &  &  & 11\\
? &  & ? &  & 3 &  & 12\\
 &  &  & ?
\end{array}$$

To complete $3+12$, we need a sum of $11$, which we could only get as $6+5$ or $7+4$. To complete $3+11$, we need $5+7$ or $4+8$. Therefore, we can't pick $7+4$ because it would wipe out both possibilities to complete the diagonal (this feels like [kakuro](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kakuro)). As such, the row needs a 6 and a 5. Which should go in the bottom left corner? Probably the middling value 6 since it's in a sum with 1 and a sum with 12:

$$\begin{array}{ccccccc}
 &  &  & 1\\
? &  & ? &  & 2 &  & ?\\
 & ? &  &  &  & 11\\
6 &  & 5 &  & 3 &  & 12\\
 &  &  & ?
\end{array}$$

This leaves $4+8$ for the diagonal on the right. But putting 4 in the top right would make the top row have no options since the numbers would have to be too big:
$$\begin{array}{ccccccc}
 &  &  & 1\\
? &  & ? &  & 2 &  & 8\\
 & ? &  &  &  & 11\\
6 &  & 5 &  & 3 &  & 12\\
 &  &  & 4
\end{array}$$
The only pair for the top row is 7,9 and the only pair for the upper diagonal is 9 and 10, so 9 must go in the intersection:
$$\begin{array}{ccccccc}
 &  &  & 1\\
7 &  & 9 &  & 2 &  & 8\\
 & 10 &  &  &  & 11\\
6 &  & 5 &  & 3 &  & 12\\
 &  &  & 4
\end{array}$$

As made clear in [How to solve this system of linear equations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/499587/how-to-solve-this-system-of-linear-equations), this is just one of many other solutions.

Answer (score 1):

My sense is that this will always come down to a bit of trial and error, though there is ample discussion around this problem (including solutions) that can be found by googling.

One such solution can be seen [here](http://mathforum.org/alejandre/magic.star/mutsumi.html).